# Best way to concatenate List of String objects?

Tags: java, string, list

What is the best way to concatenate a list of String objects? I am thinking of doing this way:

```
List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();

// add elements

if (sList != null)
{
    String listString = sList.toString();
    listString = listString.subString(1, listString.length() - 1);
}
```

I somehow found this to be neater than using the StringBuilder/StringBuffer approach.

Any thoughts/comments?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your approach is dependent on Java's ArrayList#toString() implementation.

While the implementation is documented in the Java API and very unlikely to change, there's a chance it could. It's far more reliable to implement this yourself (loops, StringBuilders, recursion whatever you like better).

Sure this approach may seem "neater" or more "too sweet" or "money" but it is, in my opinion, a worse approach.

Comment: I agree that I don't like the OP's way of doing it, but for different reasons.  (1) Doing it this way disguises the intent of the code (whereas something like `StringUtils.join` is perfectly readable). (2) It's not flexible, since you might want to change the delimiter. (Just replacing `", "` in the final string isn't a good way, since there could be `", "` embedded in the original strings.)  So even though, as you say, `ArrayList.toString` probably won't change, I still wouldn't go this route.

Comment: You can be 99.9% certain that ArrayList.toString won't change unless it becomes an attack vector somehow; backward compatibility will see to that. But I agree that using toString() is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 400):

Use one of the the [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29) methods in Apache Commons Lang.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String result = StringUtils.join(list, ", ");
```

If you are fortunate enough to be using Java 8, then it's even easier...just use [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
String result = String.join(", ", list);
```

Comment: Alternatively for Guava users:  `Joiner.on(', ').join(Collection)`

Comment: Yup, every time: Bloch, "Effective Java", Item 47: "Know and use the libraries".  The Apache Commons libraries should be the first thing to put in your build file (hopefully Gradle).  As Item 47 concludes: "To summarize, don't reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Using Guava API: `Joiner.on(', ').skipNulls().join(Iterable<?>)`. To represent null values you can use `Joiner.on(',').useForNull("#").join(Iterable<?>)`

Comment: @Gojir4 maybe you should check java version >8 before you use similar language, see the duplicate

Comment: As of Java 8 String#join is preferable (no library necessary).

Answer (score 214):

Using Java 8+

```
String str = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining())
```

or even

```
String str = String.join("", list);  // Substitute "" with your desired separator.
```

Comment: `String str = String.join("", list);` probably needs some kind of separator like `,` or `" "` right?

Answer (score 45):

A variation on codefin's answer

```
public static String concatStringsWSep(Iterable<String> strings, String separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String sep = "";
    for(String s: strings) {
        sb.append(sep).append(s);
        sep = separator;
    }
    return sb.toString();                           
}
```

Comment: @codefine See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431/algorithm-for-joining-e-g-an-array-of-strings

Comment: I really like this answer b/c you can use a foreach and it is very simple, but it is also more inefficient.  How can you make it a tighter loop?

Comment: No need to use List for strings. Collection would be more flexible

Comment: @lilalinux Changed to Iterable.

Comment: very neat trick to replace sep after the first round iteration.

Answer (score 29):

If you are developing for Android, there is [`TextUtils.join`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable)) provided by the SDK.

Answer (score 25):

This is the most elegant and clean way I've found so far:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
```

Comment: IntelliJ gives me a hint that I can improve things by changing this solution to the String.join example from other answers with the following reasoning "Reports stream API call chains which can be simplified. It allows to avoid creating redundant temporary objects when traversing a collection."

Answer (score 17):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is a pretty neat library from Google:

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(", ");
joiner.join(sList);
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen this Coding Horror blog entry?

[The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html)

I am not shure whether or not it is "neater", but from a performance-standpoint it probably won't matter much.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer String.join(list) in Java 8

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList` inherits its `toString()`-method from [`AbstractCollection`](https://openjdk.dev.java.net/source/browse/openjdk/jdk/trunk/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java?rev=257&view=markup), ie:

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Building the string yourself will be far more efficient.

---

If you really want to aggregate the strings beforehand in some sort of List, you should provide your own method to efficiently join them, e.g. like this:

```
static String join(Collection<?> items, String sep) {
    if(items.size() == 0)
        return "";

    String[] strings = new String[items.size()];
    int length = sep.length() * (items.size() - 1);

    int idx = 0;
    for(Object item : items) {
        String str = item.toString();
        strings[idx++] = str;
        length += str.length();
    }

    char[] chars = new char[length];
    int pos = 0;

    for(String str : strings) {
        str.getChars(0, str.length(), chars, pos);
        pos += str.length();

        if(pos < length) {
            sep.getChars(0, sep.length(), chars, pos);
            pos += sep.length();
        }
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: I hope you did benchmarks to confirm that your implementation is better because it not really cleaner than the toString implementation of AbstractCollection. Reader has to really focus on your implementation to understand something while the other is really easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the StringBuilder will be quick and efficient.

The basic form would look something like this:

```
public static String concatStrings(List<String> strings)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s: strings)
    {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();       
}
```

If that's too simplistic (and it probably is), you can use a similar approach and add a separator like this:

```
    public static String concatStringsWSep(List<String> strings, String separator)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    {
        sb.append(strings.get(i));
        if(i < strings.size() - 1)
            sb.append(separator);
    }
    return sb.toString();               
}
```

I agree with the others who have responded to this question when they say that you should not rely on the toString() method of Java's ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

> I somehow found this to be neater than
>   using the StringBuilder/StringBuffer
>   approach.

I guess it depends on what approach you took.

The AbstractCollection#toString() method simply iterates over all the elements and appends them to a StringBuilder.  So your method may be saving a few lines of code but at the cost of extra String manipulation.  Whether that tradeoff is a good one is up to you.

Comment: The extra String manipulation you are talking about is creating subString at the end, right?

Comment: @Jagmal, yes.  If this code gets run a lot, then you should profile to see if its a problem for you.  Otherwise you should be OK.  One thing to keep in mind is that the format of the internal toString() might change in a future JDK version.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, implementation of toString changing in future JDK version sound good enough reason for not doing it, I suppose. :)

Comment: @Jagmal: subString is really hurting you. If your listString takes n bytes, then subString temporary adds another n-4 bytes to the heap. By using StringBuilder you will receive your n-4 from "first try"

Comment: @LicenseQ: I don't know if this statement was correct at the time you wrote it, but it's not correct for any recent release of Java. The implementation of String.substring is smarter than that: it does not copy the character buffer of the original string, it simply creates a new String object pointing to the same buffer and uses a nonzero "offset" field to indicate that the string doesn't start from the beginning of the buffer. Substring allocates a String object containing three ints (count, hash and offset) and a reference to the pre-existing buffer, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than depending on `ArrayList.toString()` implementation, you could write a one-liner, if you are using java 8:

```
String result = sList.stream()
                     .reduce("", String::concat);
```

If you prefer using `StringBuffer` instead of String since `String::concat` has a runtime of `O(n^2)`, you could convert every `String` to `StringBuffer` first.

```
StringBuffer result = sList.stream()
                           .map(StringBuffer::new)
                           .reduce(new StringBuffer(""), StringBuffer::append);
```

Comment: FYI this implementation is O(n^2) as String::concat copies both strings onto a new buffer: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.concat%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

Next variation on Peter Lawrey's answer without initialization of a new string every loop turn

```
String concatList(List<String> sList, String separator)
{
    Iterator<String> iter = sList.iterator();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        sb.append(iter.next()).append( iter.hasNext() ? separator : "");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's faster to just move a pointer / set a byte to null (or however Java implements StringBuilder#setLength), rather than check a condition each time through the loop to see when to append the delimiter, you could use this method:

```
public static String Intersperse (Collection<?> collection, String delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    for (Object item : collection)
    {
        if (item == null) continue;
        sb.append (item).append (delimiter);
    }
    sb.setLength (sb.length () - delimiter.length ());
    return sb.toString ();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java 8 you can also use a reducer, something like:

```
public static String join(List<String> strings, String joinStr) {
    return strings.stream().reduce("", (prev, cur) -> prev += (cur + joinStr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the need for performance and amount of elements to be added, this might be an ok solution. If the amount of elements are high, the `Arraylist`s reallocation of memory might be a bit slower than `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Can you please explain "the Arraylists reallocation of memory might be a bit slower than StringBuilder."

Comment: Arraylist is built on standard arrays and these requires you to set an size of the array(like `int[] a = new int[10];`). This is what the ArrayList is doing for you and as you put in new elements the ArrayList will have to make a larger array and copy all the elements over to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) library, import these:

```
import static fj.pre.Monoid.stringMonoid;
import static fj.data.List.list;
import fj.data.List;
```

... then you can do this:

```
List<String> ss = list("foo", "bar", "baz");
String s = stringMonoid.join(ss, ", ");
```

Or, the generic way, if you don't have a list of Strings:

```
public static <A> String showList(List<A> l, Show<A> s) {
  return stringMonoid.join(l.map(s.showS_()), ", ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have json in your dependencies.you can use `new JSONArray(list).toString()`