# How can I add a delimiter between phrases in a list with foreach loop?

Tags: c#, string, foreach, concatenation, delimiter

I have this code:

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    result += node.InnerText;
}
```

The `InnerText` is simply 1-2 characters that never contain the `#` symbol. There can be one or more values of node in nodes.

How can I delimit each of these so that, for example, if these were the values of node:

```
"ab" and "cd"
```

That the result would be `ab#cd`.

I know I can just add `#` to the value but then what about the last character. If I just did simple adding of `#` then I would get `ab#cd#` which is not what I want.

Comment: You have a couple of options, 1) check if you're on the first item, and if not, add the delimiter *before* adding the item, or 2) use `string.Join("#", collection)` but then you need to prepare a collection of the individual elements

Comment: String.Join, take a delimeter and a enumerable string so. `result = String.join("#", nodes.Select(x=> x.InnerText))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<string> to string with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581448/join-a-string-using-delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `string.Join` is a good place to use in this situation.

```
string result = string.Join("#", nodes.Select(n => n.InnerText))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.IndexOf` to know the current index of node in `foreach` loop. You should be concatenating `node.InnerText` as long as current index of node is not equal to `(nodes.Count - 1)`.

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    //You can identify the last element in nodes like below
    if (nodes.IndexOf(node) != nodes.Count - 1) 
    {
        result += node.InnerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvotes? Please care to explain. I just gave another way of doing it.

Comment: Possible reason are too many: Answering a clear dupe. String concatenation in a tight loop, code only. I don't like the voting pattern on those question in a more general way, i don't get the downvote or the down votes here

Comment: @xdtTransform I just posted my answer very quickly and thought to update in next few minutes. Anyway your comment is fair enough. I'm agree with you. I should have chose to mark question as a duplicate.