# Sqlite Query for multiple values in one column

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to do query in table for field id with some vales like 1,5,4,11 which will come from previous screen according to selection.

```
cursor = database.query(tablename,
                    new String[] { "TopName" }, "id =?", new String[]{"2,3"}, null, null, null);
```

When I do like this, I am getting cursor count 0, with new String[]{"2"} I am getting value I want for all ids with values in string array like OR which have value in that column.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the IN operator like this,

```
cursor = database.query(tablename, new String[] {"TopName"}, "id IN(?,?)", 
                                        new String[]{"2","3"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: what if we want to match with one more column with the same scene?

Answer (score 17):

The correct syntax for using the IN operator in Android's ContentProvider is as follows:

```
cursor = database.query(contentUri, projection, "columname IN(?,?)", new String[]{"value1" , "value2"}, sortOrder);
```

Alternatively, we can also use,

```
cursor = database.query(contentUri, projection, "columnName IN(?)", new String[] {" 'value1' , 'value2' "}, sortOrder);
```

**Note that we need single quotes** around each comma-separated value in the arguments for second case, otherwise the whole string will be treated as one value for the column. The SQL will treat it as

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName IN ('value1,value2')

instead of the correct syntax

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName IN ('value1' , 'value2')

Answer (score 5):

VolkerK was first to correctly answer the question, but for the sake of completeness here is a full example of how to use the IN operator:

```
cursor = database.query(tablename,
                new String[] { "TopName" }, "id IN (?)", new String[]{"2,3"}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [IN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) instead of equality comparison (=).

Answer (score 1):

For the SelectionArgs section I think you need to change:

```
new String[]{"2,3"}
```

To

```
new String[]{"2","3"}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for, and it would actually cause an error since the number of supplied arguments is different from the number of `?` fields. VolkerK's answer is correct.

Comment: Oh ok...I see it now.  I have the same question as ud_an then.  How do you use the "IN" operator in the query above?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put this here since a compendium of answers helped me putting multiple (unknown) values in `SQLiteDatabase.query()` and the one-question-mark did not work for me. Hope helps anyone

```
// API > 24
protected String attributesAsMarks(String[] attributes) {
    List<String> marks = Collections.nCopies(attributes.length, "?");

    return marks.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}

// I'm using API > 15
protected String attributesAsMarks(String[] attributes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";

    for (String s : attributes) {
        if (s == null) continue;

        sb.append(separator).append("?");
        separator = ",";
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thanks to

- @Lalit
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600690/1358777
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38546936/1358777
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/524089/1358777