# How to select from a list of rows using android contentprovider

Tags: android

I have a list of row ids and i'm trying to query them using contentprovider. This is the method and parameters:

```
   Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String      sortOrder)
```

String selection is what determines the ID of the row. I have a list of row IDs and want to query the list. How would I implement this?

EDIT:

If anyone was interested, I finally solved this. I was able to achieve this by using a text filter and onTextChangedListener

```
   EditText itemName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    itemName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String wildcardQuery = "%" + s + "%";
            Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    DrugContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    DataBaseHelper.COLUMN1 + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[]{wildcardQuery},
                    DataBaseHelper.COLUMN2 + " ASC");


            testadapter = new TestPackageAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), cur);

            testadapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            mList.setAdapter(testadapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create the value list (?,?,?...) see here [Sqlite Query for multiple values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343946/sqlite-query-for-multiple-values-in-one-columm) It should work the same in the content provider since most just pass through to a sqlite database, and you didn't mention what content provider you are using.

Similar to

```
cursor = database.query(contentUri, projection, "columname IN(?,?)", new String[]{"value1" , "value2"}, sortOrder);
```

Comment: i'm using android.content.ContentProvider. What if the number of row changes. How would I implement that with the IN operator. It look like it is predefined to two IDs.

Comment: You need to use a StringBuilder or somesuch and create the IN(...) list.

Comment: I tried implementing it using string builder but I get java.lang.RuntimeException: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IN": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, col_01 FROM table_01 WHERE (_id = IN (150,120)) ORDER BY col_01 ASC

Comment: You probably need to use quotes like lastname IN ('Hernandez', 'Jones', 'Roberts', 'Ruiz' but in your case you should follow my example and use ? parameters and the string array of values.

Comment: I gave up using that approach and went with a relational database. I created a new table to hold the ids of the table i'm trying to query. Here is the example I used, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/.