# What's the most elegant/concise way of printing all strings in a list into a single string?

Tags: java, string, list

Is there an elegant way (elegant meaning without an iterator or a loop) to print every member of Java's `List<Sting>` object into a comma-separated string?

E.g., Java's version of Perl's `my $allElementsString = join(",", @myStrings);`

I checked List interface and didn't find anything promising (my best guess was to use `toArray` and then Array's `toString`?)

Comment: `List.toString()` would return a comma-separated list, but it would include braces on the end.

Comment: @zch - probably a closer one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in the JDK to do this directly. You can implement your own joiner with `StringBuilder` or use a 3rd party library like Guava

```
List<String> string = ...;
String list = Joiner.on(",").join(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is a list of Strings then simply print it :

```
System.out.println(yourList);
```

If it is a list of custom objects then make sure you have overriden `toString` method in your custom class to print the List objects properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think most people use [Apache Commons' StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29):

```
List<String> yourStrings = /* something */;
String commaSeperated = StringUtils.join(yourStrings, ',');
```

The [Apache Commons libraries](https://commons.apache.org/) are extremely convenient. I'd recommend looking at them (or Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
String result = list.toString().substring(1, list.toString().length() - 1);
System.out.println(result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Writing it as a one-liner does not pay off calling `list.toString()` twice, especially in real-life code where the list might be large. Having one more line of code for a local variable is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the JDK but there is [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) and other utility libraries also offer similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Any `toString` method you might apply to List or the Array wouldn't be formatted in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Guava as already pointed out, or Apache Common's `StringUtils`:

```
StringUtils.join( list, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Best way to concatenate List of String objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523871/best-way-to-concatenate-list-of-string-objects)

*Quoted,
Use one of the the StringUtils.join methods in Apache Commons Lang.*

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String result = StringUtils.join(list, ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) method