# simple mathematical expression parsing

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I try to write `equals` override function. I think I have written right but the problem is that parsing the expression. I have an array type of `ArrayList<String>` it takes inputs from keyboard than evaluate the result. I could compare with another `ArrayList<String>` variable but how can I compare the `ArrayList<String>` to `String`. For example,

```java
String expr = "(5 + 3) * 12 / 3";
ArrayList<String> userInput = new ArrayList<>();
userInput.add("(");
userInput.add("5");
userInput.add(" ");
userInput.add("+");
userInput.add(" ");
userInput.add("3");
.
.
userInput.add("3");
userInput.add(")");
```

then convert userInput to String then compare using equals
As you see it is too long when a test is wanted to apply. 
I have used to split but It splits combined numbers as well. like `12` to `1` and `2`

```java
public fooConstructor(String str) 
{
   // ArrayList<String> holdAllInputs; it is private member in class
   holdAllInputs = new ArrayList<>();

    String arr[] = str.split("");

    for (String s : arr) {
        holdAllInputs.add(s);
    }
}
```

As you expect it doesn't give the right result. How can it be fixed? Or can someone help to writing regular expression to parse it properly as wanted?
As output I get:

```
(,5, ,+, ,3,), ,*, ,1,2, ,/, ,3
```

instead of

```
(,5, ,+, ,3,), ,*, ,12, ,/, ,3
```

Comment: How do you add the 12? `userInput.add("12");` or `userInput.add("1");` `userInput.add("2");` ?

Comment: `userInput.add("12");` @guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Regular Expression** which helps you here is

```
"(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])"
```

and of course, you need to avoid unwanted spaces.

Here we go,

```
String expr = "(5 + 3) * 12 / 3";
.
. // Your inputs
.
String arr[] = expr.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])");
for (String s : arr) 
{
    System.out.println("Element : " + s);
}
```

Please see my expiriment : http://rextester.com/YOEQ4863

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
this makes all the inputs into one string which can then be can be compared against the expression to see if it is equal

String x = "";    

for(int i = 0; i < holdAllInputs.length; i++){
    x = x + holdAllInputs.get(i);
}

if(expr == x){
   //do something equal
}else{
   //do something if not equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the input into tokens for which you don't have a regex, it would be good to move ahead with joining the strings in the List like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : userInput)
{
    sb.append(s);
}
```

then use `sb.toString()` later for comparison. I would not advice String concatenation using `+` operator details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do).

Another approach to this would be to use one of the the [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29) methods in Apache Commons Lang.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String result = StringUtils.join(list, "");
```

If you are fortunate enough to be using Java 8, then it's even easier...just use [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
String result = String.join("", list);
```

More details on this approach available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523871/best-way-to-concatenate-list-of-string-objects)

Comment: my problem is not related to ArrayList variable, it is about string variable in fooConstructor. After parsing string, I can construct then compare.

Comment: That's what I wanted to say. Do not parse the String variable in `fooConstructor`. Instead combine the Strings in List to perform comparison. (Unless you want to use some regex which is hard to digest)