# Changing the format of list / array in URL [Retrofit 2]

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit2

As stated in [the Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) above the `@Query` annotation:

> Passing a List or array will result in a query parameter for each
>   non-null item.

---

As of now my call looks something like this:

```
@GET("questions")
Call<List<QuestionHolder>> getQuestionsExcludingTheSpecified(
        @Query("exclude_ids") long[] excludedQuestionIds
);
```

This works but results in fairly long URLs quite fast.

E.g. for `excludedQuestionIds = new long[]{1L, 4L, 16L, 64L}` the request URL already will be `/questions?exclude_ids=1&exclude_ids=4&exclude_ids=16&exclude_ids=64`.

---

Is there an easy way to exchange this behaviour resulting in arrays formatted as `exclude_ids=[1,4,16,64]` or something similar?

What came to my mind yet was, to:

- use JsonArray as parameter, but then I need to convert every array / list before making the call
- intercept every request and compress duplicated keys
- override the built-in `@Query` decorator

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with the Interceptor approach. I simply change any outgoing request that includes more than one value for a single query parameter.

```
public class QueryParameterCompressionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        HttpUrl url = request.url();
        for (String parameterName : url.queryParameterNames()) {
            List<String> queryParameterValues = url.queryParameterValues(parameterName);

            if (queryParameterValues.size() > 1) {
                String formattedValues= "[" + TextUtils.join(",", queryParameterValues) + "]";

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .url(
                                url.newBuilder()
                                        .removeAllQueryParameters(parameterName)
                                        .addQueryParameter(parameterName, formattedValues)
                                        .build()
                        ).build();
            }
        }

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
```

---

**non android solution**

TextUtils is part of the Android SDK, in case you're not developing for Android you might exchange TextUtils.join for a method like this:

```
    public static String concatListOfStrings(String separator, Iterable<String> strings) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String str : strings) {
            sb.append(separator).append(str);
        }

        sb.delete(0, separator.length());

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

You may also have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523871/best-way-to-concatenate-list-of-string-objects) for more solutions regarding the concatenation.