# How to get to a particular element in a List in java?

Tags: java, list

I have a CSV file. It has many lines. In each line there are multiple values separated by commas.

I am using OPENCSV to extract data from the file. I want to have the ability to directly go to any particular line which is in List data structure.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
                    "myfile.csv"));
            try {
                List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
                for (String[] s : myEntries) {
                    System.out.println("Next item: " + s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This prints

```
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@6c8b058b
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@1b192059
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@e9ac0f5
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@51f21c50
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@6e20f237
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@34fe315d
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@1c5aebd9
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@1532021a
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@62803d5
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@2d13981b
Next item: [Ljava.lang.String;@61672bbb
```

I want to know if there is anyway I could access individual lines, elements via List.

i.e

```
    1,2,3,4,5
    6,7,8,9,10
    11,12,13,14
    15,16,17,18
```

I want String[] nextLine = 1,2,3,4,5 (where nextLine[0] = 1 nextLine[1] = 2 etc)  and in the next iteration nextLine should be 6,7,8,9,10 etc

Comment: Why not add another for loop?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `List` interface supports random access via the `get` method - to get line 0, use `list.get(0)`.  You'll need to use array access on that, ie, `lines.get(0)[0]` is the first element of the first line.

See the javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29).

Answer (score 4):

The `toString` method of array types in Java isn't particularly meaningful, other than telling you what that is an array of.

You can use [`java.util.Arrays.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) for that.

Or if your lines only contain numbers, and you want a line as `1,2,3,4...` instead of `[1, 2, 3, ...]`, you can use:

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(someArray).replaceAll("\\]| |\\[","")
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point:

```
for (String[] s : myEntries) {
   System.out.println("Next item: " + s);
}
```

You need to join the array of Strings in a line. Check this post:
[A method to reverse effect of java String.split()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794248/a-method-to-reverse-effect-of-java-string-split)

Answer (score 0):

You have about 98% right. The only issue is that you're trying to print out an String[] which does not print the way you'd like. Instead try this...

```
for (String[] s : myEntries) {
    System.out.print("Next item: " + s[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(", " + s[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

This way you're accessing each string in the array instead of the array itself.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

String[] is an array of Strings. Such an array is internally a class. Like all classes that don't explicitly extend some other class, it extends Object implicitly. The method `toString()` of class Object, by default, gives you the representation you see: the class name, followed by @, followed by the hash code in hex. Since the String[] class doesn't override the toString() method, you get that as a result.

Create some method that outputs the array elements for you. Iterate over the array and use `System.out.print()` (not print**ln**) on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
                "myfile.csv"));
        try {
            List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
            for (String[] s : myEntries) {
               for(String ss : s) {
                   System.out.print(", " + ss);
               }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the split function of String [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), and use it something like this `String[] results = input.split("\\s+");`. The regular expresion bit spilts on whitespaces, it should do the trick