# String[] args values into a single string

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A method to reverse effect of java String.split()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794248/a-method-to-reverse-effect-of-java-string-split)

How do I take all the values within String[] args and make it into a single String variable?

Comment: Can you show us what result that you want?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a duplicate.  Can it be closed please?

Comment: There are *many* other Q/A's that deal with this; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-oposite-of-spl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer Apache Commons [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).  `StringUtils.join(Object[] array, String separator)` will join all the objects in the array with the given separator.

If you want a subarray of your current array (e.g. skip the first three elements), use this:

```
StringUtils.join(ArrayUtils.subarray(myArray, 3, myArray.length), ",");
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Iterate over the array
2. concatenate the strings together

Note: it's more efficient to use a StringBuilder object, but this is a simpler example:

```
public String concat(String[] args) {
  String result = ""
  for (String arg : args) {
    result += arg;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to remove say the first 3 values defined within the args? So start from the 4 arg and then on

Comment: Use `for(i = 3; i < args.length; i++)` instead of the colon syntax.

Comment: Or you could use Apache Commons `ArrayUtils.subarray`.

Comment: for(i = 3; i < args.length; i++) doesnt seem to be working right with me. any idea?

Comment: for(int i=3;i<args.length;i++){result+=args[i];}

Comment: @user372671 See my updated answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString()` method and within this method, you can implement by doing loop through the String array and return the concatenated string in the format that you want.