# Jsoup doesn't work properly with encoded link containing non-letter characters

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm creating a discord bot for an online game and one of the bots' features is using a webcrawler to get item info.

My problem is that when I use an UTF-8 encoded URL Jsoup doesn't work for some reason.

I did try to iterate through all of the elements with the same class name but that doesn't work at all. It looks like the class is fully absent there.

```java
String url = "http://coryn.club/item.php?name=";

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(arguments.get(0));

for (int i = 1; i < arguments.size(); i++)
    stringBuilder.append(" ").append(arguments.get(i));

url = url + URLEncoder.encode(stringBuilder.toString(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(url);
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element table = document.getElementsByClass("table table-striped").first();
System.out.println(table == null ? "Table is null" : "Table is not null"); //returns that the table is null only on the %27 link
```

For instance, the url: http://coryn.club/item.php?name=dark+general would totally work but the url http://coryn.club/item.php?name=dark+general%27s will not. The only difference is the %27 near the end.

I do get a null value with the element of class "table table-striped".

Just to note that I use the same code in both URL's but only the first one does work.

Also to note that if you do open the page in a browser it will work and you will still see the HTML data with inspect element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like if you use raw (not-encoded) query data like

```
String url = "http://coryn.club/item.php?name=dark general's";
```

you will get correct results.

This suggests that Jsoup encodes those parameters on its own, which means that if you use data in form `dark+general%27s` it will be encoded again causing final URL to contain `dark%2Bgeneral%2527s`.

Because of that server after decoding it will see value of `name` as `dark+general%27s` NOT as `dark general's` and will search and fail to find result matching it. Because of that there will be no result table in returned HTML.

So **don't encode your data, let Jsoup do it for you**.

---

BTW: you can also change your code into more (IMO) readable version

```
Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("http://coryn.club/item.php")
        .data("name", stringBuilder.toString()) //query parameters - don't encode manually
        .get();
```

Notice that `stringBuilder.toString()` is not encoded by us, it contains raw data like `dark general's`.

---

BTW 2: if `arguments` is defined to contain CharacterSequence like String, for instance `List<String>` since Java 8 instead of

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(arguments.get(0));

for (int i = 1; i < arguments.size(); i++)
    stringBuilder.append(" ").append(arguments.get(i));
```

you can use

```
String joined = String.join(" ", arguments);
```

or

```
String joined = arguments.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

More info: [Java equivalent of PHP's implode(',' , array_filter( array () ))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248119/java-equivalent-of-phps-implode-array-filter-array)