# Java equivalent to Explode and Implode(PHP)

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am new in Java although had a good experience in PHP, and looking for perfect replacement for explode and implode (available in PHP) functions in Java.

I have Googled for the same but not satisfied with the results.
Anyone has the good solution for my problem will be appreciated.

For example:

```
String s = "x,y,z";
//Here I need a function to divide the string into an array based on a character.
array a = javaExplode(',', s);  //What is javaExplode?
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Desired output:

```
[x, y, z]
```

Comment: OK, what solutions have you found so far ?

Comment: This is practically the same as [A method to reverse effect of java String.split()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794248)

Comment: why this question is down voted ? and off topic ?? Please suggest to avoid for next questions.

Comment: I think based on the view count this question is not that bad at all. I agree it is a weird question but a lot of us PHP programmers just google for java explode and then get this as an correct answer.

Comment: Now it's November 2014, and I googled java string explode, and this question still came out as the top result. I think the status 'closed as off-topic' should be lifted, as this is not off topic at all for me.

Comment: February 2016, this question is the main result for "java explode".

Comment: I think they just want desired code and desired results with an example.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The [Javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) reveals that `String.split()` is what you're looking for in regard to `explode`.

Java does not include a "implode" of "join" equivalent. Rather than including a giant external dependency for a simple function as the other answers suggest, you may just want to write a couple lines of code. There's a number of ways to accomplish that; using a `StringBuilder` is one:

```
String foo = "This,that,other";
String[] split = foo.split(",");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    sb.append(split[i]);
    if (i != split.length - 1) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
String joined = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks u guys for all your answers .

Comment: Split does indeed use a regular expression (in PHP, Perl, Java, etc.).  If you want to split on another symbol, it needs to be escaped, like this: String[] split = foo.split("\\\(");

Comment: Note that since **Java 8** we actually have `String#join` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)). For your example: `String joined = String.join(" ", split);`. The method uses the `StringJoiner` class.

Answer (score 25):

`String.split()` can provide you with a replacement for `explode()`

For a replacement of `implode()` I'd advice you to write either a custom function or use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s `StringUtils.join()` functions.

Answer (score 17):

Good alternatives are the String.split and StringUtils.join methods.

Explode :

```
String[] exploded="Hello World".split(" ");
```

Implode :

```
String imploded=StringUtils.join(new String[] {"Hello", "World"}, " ");
```

Keep in mind though that StringUtils is in an external library.

Comment: Where do you find StringUtils? I find this class in com.sun.internal and com.sun.deploy but I don't think that it is a good idea to directly use classes under com.sun `packages such as sun., that are outside of the Java platform, can be different across OS platforms (Solaris, Windows, Linux, Macintosh, etc.) and can change at any time without notice with SDK versions`

Comment: Ok, after your edit, I see that this class comes from an external lib

Comment: ...which is [Appache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) (I guess): [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 5):

[`java.lang.String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but I think [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is Java equivalent to PHP `explode`. As for `implode`, standart library does not provide such functionality. You just iterate over your array and build string using [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)/[StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). Or you can try excellent [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Splitter](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) and [Joiner](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#joiner) or `split/join` methods from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

Comment: All links are valid except for Guava, since 3 years passed and they moved to GitHub. I've updated the comment with new links.

Answer (score -1):

if you are talking about in the reference of String Class.  so you can use

> **subString/split**

for Explode & use String

> **concate**

for Implode.

Comment: `concate` is not equivalent to `implode`.