# How to assign variables in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to assign variables in a string.

```
 String s = "102, 145, 163, 124";
```

I want to assign a separate variable like below;

```
num1 = 102;
num2 = 145;
num3 = 163;
num4 = 124;
```

I need to do it programatically since the values will change and increase so whatever is in string s is assigned a variable.
Thanks

Comment: this is java right?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773599/explode-and-implodejust-like-php-in-java

Comment: yes,sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: If there will ever be more than 4 numbers, you should look into arrays

Comment: Are the `num`s ints? Or Strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split then parse your strings

```
String s = "102, 145, 163, 124";
String[] sArray = s.split(",");
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String item:sArray){
  integers.add(Integer.parseInt(s.replace(",","")));
}
```

Comment: You might want to also add a trim() to the end of that replace() or else his Strings will throw an IllegalArgumentException or numberFormatException (I can't remember which, but I'm guessing the number one)

Comment: Can be a trim or change the split to "[0-9]*" but I think the Integer.parseInt(string) can parse numbers with white space in the String (can't test right now)...

Answer (score 2):

If the values are going to change, you should look into using an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which will be dynamic and vary with the length of your data.

For instance, you could easily convert all that data to an ArrayList like this:

```
String string = "102, 145, 163, 124";
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String s : string.split(",")) list.add(Integer.parseInt(s.trim()));
```

Each item would then be accessible by calling it's index like so:

```
int num0 = list.get(0);
int last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

Storing data in lists is a dynamic approach that's scale-able.

Comment: How can I loop through the items so that they can be written like int[] xAxis = new int[]{102, 145,163,124}; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because there are a dynamic number of values, you need to use an array (or ArrayList):

```
String s = "102, 145, 163, 124";

String[] nums = s.split(", ");

// just printing the array
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
```

Output of that:

```
102
145
163
124
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, ", ");
for (int i = 0; i < tokenizer.countTokens(); i++)
```

Comment: How can I keep the resulting variables in an array? Something like int[] arr = new int[resulting variables in the string]

Comment: Define an array int array = new array[tokenizer.countTokens()]. Then array[i] = tokenizer.nextToken() inside loop.

Comment: so far this is what I have done, String str =   "102, 145, 163, 124";
       String[] nums = str.split(",");
       
       int[] newArr = new int[nums.length];
       for(int i = 0;i < newArr.length;i++)
       {
          
          newArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
          int results = newArr[i];
       }
              
           int[] xAxis = new int[]{results}; // but this code is not working. I need to keep the results in the int[] xAxis.