# How to convert character "S" to Seconds?

Tags: freemarker

I have a variable with values like

30S, 2H, 5D

```
where S,H and D stands for Seconds, Hours and Days.
```

I want to extract `"S/H/D"` from the variable and convert into the time period - string `"Seconds/Hours/Days"`.

Is there any builtin methods that I can use to resolve above issue.

Comment: Look at the answer of Brian on this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773599/java-equivalent-to-explode-and-implodephp

Answer (score 0):

In freemarker you can use the built-in `replace` method.

It is used to replace all occurrences of a string in the original string with another string.

For example,

```
${"this is a car acarus"?replace("car", "bulldozer")}
```

will print:

```
this is a bulldozer abulldozerus
```

Check more here: [Built-in for strings](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace)